# WCF Service hosted in Azure Cloud Service errors after published

Tags: wcf, iis, azure

I have a project with several WCF services (mix of REST and SOAP).  The project has been running On-Prem for 6 months without an issue.  We are moving this to Azure but have run into an issue that will prevent us from going live.

The project uses Autofac for it's IOC.  We are gonig to host this in a Cloud Service in Azure.  Everything appears to work correctly when running locally in the Azure Emulator however once we deploy using the Cloud Service project, everything builds and deploys correctly, but we receive the following error when trying to access a service.

```
Server Error in '/' Application.


Value cannot be null. Parameter name: key

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: key Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.

Parameter name: key]

   System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument argument) +48

   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.FindEntry(TKey key) +38

   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.TryGetValue(TKey key, TValue& value) +20

   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.WebHttpDispatchOperationSelector..ctor(ServiceEndpoint endpoint) +2459

   System.ServiceModel.Description.WebHttpBehavior.GetOperationSelector(ServiceEndpoint endpoint) +125

   System.ServiceModel.Description.WebHttpBehavior.ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher) +1955

   System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.InitializeServiceHost(ServiceDescription description, ServiceHostBase serviceHost) +4245

   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.InitializeRuntime() +119

   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout) +45

   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout) +553

   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.ActivateService(ServiceActivationInfo serviceActivationInfo, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +350

   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +1614

[ServiceActivationException: The service '/Event/Calendar' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: Value cannot be null.

Parameter name: key.]

   System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +925

   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +528

   System.ServiceModel.Activation.AspNetRouteServiceHttpHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +107

   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult ar) +151
```

It appears that it's having an issue with the service configuration endpoint.  That is registered through Autofac WCF integration using the OOTB RouteTable here:

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("Event/Calendar", new AutofacWebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(CalendarSvc)));
```

All of this works fine in IIS and the local Azure emulator, but once deployed to the cloud service is where we get an issue.

Comment: Do you have any sub-domains/projects in azure? is your WCF project is the parent project/domain?

Comment: we do not have any sub domains, so yes its the only parent domain

Comment: In azure parent directoy doesn't have a virtual directory name but in local IIS it does, so for testing purpose take any of your REST url open it in the browser without virtual directory name & ser if that works for you.

Answer (score 3):

Observed exactly problem. Solved by canceling IntelliTrace on this hosted service.

I did publishing from VS2013 and marked "Enable IntelliTrace" during publishing. Once I canceled this option and re-publish - all works properly....

Comment: Yes. I've run into the same issue with IntelliTrace enabled.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue and this solved it. Would you know why this is the case? IntelliTrace is important to our project so we'd rather have it enabled. But of course, a working service is always preferred. I just hope you could point me in the right direction as to why IntelliTrace seems to be the culprit here. 

Anyone?

Comment: @JcFx maybe you could help me shed a light on this too?

Comment: @iamnobody - No, I never found out why. Just stopped using IntelliTrace on that project.